# Difference between passing JQuery.append.bind vs anonymous function to a Array.forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I get two different behaviors out of these, I was hoping someone could explain why.

```
function Test( id ) {
           this.target = $(id);
           this.children = [ $('<div/>').text("A"), $('<div/>').text("B") ];
}

// will add 0 1 A B
Test.prototype.addToTarget = function() {
     this.children.forEach(this.target.append.bind(this.target));
};

// will add A B           
Test.prototype.addToTargetEx = function() {            
    var target = this.target;
    this.children.forEach(function(child){
        target.append(child);
    });
};
```

Comment: Could add some context? What would the two different behaviours be? The calling to the two different functions?

Comment: My guess is one is iterating over each property in object while the other iterates only over DOM elements.

Comment: Or a similarly limited scope : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you're binding the `this` value, but `forEach` passes 3 arguments to its callback, which are the item, the index and the original array.

In the second version, you're manually passing only the first argument given to the callback, and ignoring the last two.

---

So (for illustration of the issue) you can force your second version to behave like the first like this...

```
    this.children.forEach(function(child, idx, arr){
        target.append(child, idx, arr); // Passing all 3 args
    });
```

Now it's clearer that `.append()` is receiving 3 values on each iteration.

There's not really any way around this using `.bind()`. If `.append()` were made to only recognize the first argument passed, then it would work.

---

One thing you could do would be to create your own custom `.bindN` method. Instead of being able to bind `this` and individual arguments, it could bind `this` and receive a "limiter" that will limit the number of arguments it's allowed to receive.

It could look like this:

```
Function.prototype.bindN = function(thisArg, n) {
    var origFunc = this;
    return function() {
        return origFunc.apply(thisArg, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, n));
    }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
this.children.forEach(this.target.append.bindN(this.target, 1));
```